# Fluid-width Google maps

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a 2 column layout for the website, with the left fixed-width column and a right fluid-width Google maps that fills the rest of the width not taken by the left column.

**Problem:** However I cannot seem to get Google maps `<div id="map_canvas">` to be fluid and take up the rest of the width. Did I set it up wrongly? Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<div id="main_container">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="map_container">
            <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#map_container {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
}

#map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-order: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Here is the fix [Set Google Maps Container DIV width and height 100%](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18147172/782535)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you try to use `style="width:100%;height:100%"` on your map div, as you have done by giving 100% height, you get a map div that has zero height. That's because the div tries to be a percentage of the size of the `<body>`, but by default the  has an indeterminate height.

There are ways to determine the height of the screen and use that number of pixels as the height of the map div, but a simple alternative is to change the `<body>` so that its height is 100% of the page. We can do this by applying `style="height:100%"` to both the `<body>` and the `<html>.` (We have to do it to both, otherwise the `<body>` tries to be 100% of the height of the document, and the default for that is an indeterminate height.)

Re-adjusting your css values should resolve your issue.

Comment: @RainbowHat; glad that I could be helpful