# Google Maps API Javascript V3-Responsive

Tags: javascript, google-maps, responsive-design

Normally I would include a static image into my webpage for a google map, this way I can make the image responsive, but for this project I would like the interaction of the map, zoom, drag etc.

So I have used the google maps api (javascript V3). The only problem I have here is that the image pulled in is not responsive. I would like to get it to behave the same as a static image, is this possible?

I have followed the instructions and even wrapped the map_canvas in a div that has a specific height and width, though I suspect this is where my problem lies. But without actually declaring the content (the map) as an img I'm unsure what to do here. has anyone got around this before?

EDIT

Just to clarify what I mean by responsive, I would like the map to behave in the same way an img would if you set img{max-width:100%}

Comment: what do you mean 'responsive'?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768580/fluid-width-google-maps

Comment: @Richlewis, what did you settle on in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give [Google Maps Image APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/) a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was using static images in the beginning, only problem there no interaction