# Basic google map - Cant get it to display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I'm trying to learn how to code HTML and javascript but no matter what I do I can't get the map t display in the "main" div here on my site:

http://jsfiddle.net/W4mXP/10/

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <div id="topbar">
        <div class="left">
        Logo
        </div>
        <div class="right">
<form>
  <div id="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
  </div>
</form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Map -->
    <div id="main"></div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <div id="bottombar">
        <div class="left">
        Name
        </div>
        <div class="right">
        About
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var map;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('main'),
            mapOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fluid-width Google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768580/fluid-width-google-maps) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4mXP/20/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/W4mXP/19/

You need to apply the absolute height and width to the map container and change the initialize mode

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    initialize();
});
```

See the changes that I make

Comment: He shouldn't need to change to use document.ready - the Google event listener for the window load event should be sufficient.

Comment: ... unless you're alluding to the same problem @dmk is pointing out, which is with it not working on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that your js in jsFiddle is executed on window load event (you can change that in the menu on the left) so google maps `load` event never getting fired because everything is loaded already.

Change that option in jsFiddle to `onDomReady` and it should work fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/G6YMm/